# Open 600K+ files JSON Decode get data and Fwrite Fast

Tags: php, arrays, json, fwrite

```
foreach($files as $file){
    $fna = json_decode(file_get_contents("/home/data/msware/$file.json"), true);
    foreach($fna["sware"] as $fnas){
        if(isset($fnas["name"])){
            $sware= $fnas["name"];  
            fwrite(fopen("/home/data/sware/$sware.json","a+"),"$file");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Problem... I have `600K+` Files in this directory
`/home/data/msware/*`

I have to `file_get_contents` and `json_decode` each of these files in order to make main file and this takes 5-10 minutes which is absolutely absurd.

Is there a faster method i can get to `file_get_contents, json_decode & fwrite`?

Comment: Presumably putting the data in a database is out question?

Comment: So how often do you have to do this?

Comment: @user3783243 iv'e tried database with Word Press but there's too much load on site and mysql crashes... so i exported all my data to my own cms with static data instead of database. Now i'm facing this problem.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Website gets updated once everyday so once everyday.

Comment: So 10 minutes to do all that using the file system I would say is pretty magical. As its only once a day, is it worth shaving a few milliseconds

Comment: Do all these updates appear in a blob all in one go? Or do they accumulate over time?

Comment: file_get_contents, cant be improved, decoding to an array might be an additional internal call. $sware doesn't need to be defined, `"` over single quotes when not needed, fwrite(fopen instead of FILE_APPEND, you could use a generator, but you wont shave much off, maybe try a diff lang or compile to extension with [zephir](https://zephir-lang.com/en) lang

Comment: i was using `glob` at first but that used to crash the server then instead i started using `DirectoryIterator` and it became less time consuming.

Comment: @RiggsFolly All in one go... when i update or add new content files time change so i use 'DirectoryIterator' then time to `sort` files, add to array, `foreach` and `fwrite`.

Comment: So `/home/data/msware/` suddenly gets 600k files dropped into it?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Didn't try `zephir` yet... will give it a try.

Comment: @RiggsFolly No. `/home/data/msware/` already has 600k files/jsons. I just add more files in it or update old ones. This is where new jsons gets their data `"/home/data/sware/$sware.json"`... 19 New Jsons to be exact.

Comment: So how about first thing you do is identify the changed files and then you will only have to do the business on a few files

Comment: Forget that, I see now you are building one BIG file from all the 600k files. What on earth do you use that for in the real system

Comment: @RiggsFolly lol... i'm so confused on what iv'e done already. If i use `mysql` system crashes, i'm using `json` now and it's directly using too much memory.

Comment: It really looks like you need to site down and have a serious think about what you are doing and the best way to store this data. Can you give us some clues about the data

Comment: @RiggsFolly also Not 1 Json, 19 to be exact as i said... 19 `jsons` with same `id` or `category` containing names of 600k filenames.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the inputs and the generated outputs

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is the Output I write in files: `["revenge","war","world","newton"]`... also used as `URI` for our CMS